# Hacer un DELETE en Java

Tags: java, mysql, delete

Al pulsar el botón de eliminar me resuelve este mensaje:

[image: Salida]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public void eliminaregistro(){
        
        int filaseleccionada = tablalumnos.getSelectedRow();
        
        try {
            String SQL = "Delete from inventario where n_serie= " +tablalumnos.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 0);
            Statement st =con.createStatement();
            int n = st.executeUpdate(SQL);
            if (n>=0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Eliminado");
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de Registro" + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Es importante en este sitio realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Te servirá para saber como funciona y además podrás ir consiguiendo puntos de  [reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/586/por-qu%c3%a9-necesito-50-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n-para-comentar-qu%c3%a9-alternativa-tengo?rq=1) para poder comentar en otras respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate de que es ahí el error. El mensaje hace referencia a un campo llamado serie y en tu código no se ve ningún campo llamado así.

Por otra parte, después de construir la sentencia SQL puedes hacer un system.out.println(SQL); y comprobar que lo que quieres borrar está bien escrito en la instrucción SQL que intentas ejecutar.